# Merging ontologies with common property

Tags: owl, semantic-web, semantics, protege

I am studying OWL and now I'm trying to merge two ontologies.

My issue is with two properties that share the name (not the whole IRI but only the name).

For my example, it would make sense to merge those two properties to be the same property. Is there a way to do that?

I tried with "Equivalent to", but the doesn't solve the problem in this sense. Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly is shared? An IRI doesn't have "names" or similar things. Can you give an example please?

Comment: @UninformedUser for example, if I had 
http://www.w3.org/some_iri#likes
and also
http://www.w3.org/some_other_iri#likes.

By "name" i mean the part after the hashtag, "likes", that Protege treats as the name.

So, some individuals are connected through the first property and some others through the second one.
And now I want to have "universal" property #likes that includes all the information concerning both properties.

Comment: `owl:equivalentProperty`(in Protege indeed the `Equivalent To` widget) would be the way to go. Or you introduce your own property and make both a subproperty of yours.

Comment: @UninformedUser but then I'd have duplicates when reasoning, wouldn't I? I was kind of hoping at the end to have only one property, and not two or three.

Comment: not sure what exactly you're asking. if you make `p1` and `p2` subproperty of `p` and then asking for all `x,y` with `p(x,y)` you would get a **set** of pairs - no duplicates. Indeed, when materializing all inferences, it would return for each `p1(x,y)` also `p(x,y)` - if you don't want this you have to do data integration by yourself just collect all axioms `p1(x,y)` and `p2(x,y)`and add `p(x,y)` to your new ontology

Answer (score 0):

You can create IRI in the ontologyX and copy the IRI and use it in the ontologyY. Why not?